# jest.js and useValue stub for provider not working in angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a service with a simple GET method:

```
export class MyService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getUsers() {
    const path = 'https://gorest.co.in/public/v2/users'

    return this.http.get(path)
  }
}
```

Next I'm injecting it into a component:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  users: any[]

  constructor(private _myService: MyService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this._myService.getUsers().subscribe((usersRes) => {
      this.users = usersRes
    })
  }
}
```

I Also have a simple stub for users:

```
const usersMock = [
  {
    gender: 'female',
    id: 3971,
    name: 'Piotreczi Krawaczi',
  },
]

const myServiceStub = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
  getUsers: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(of(usersMock))
})
```

...and then I want to use it in TestBed in app.components.spec.ts.

```
beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    providers: [{ MyService, useValue: myServiceStub }],
  }).compileComponents()

  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent)
  component = fixture.componentInstance
}))
```

...finally I want to test that, users isn't empty:

```
it('should get Users', fakeAsync(() => {
  fixture.detectChanges()
  expect(component.users.length).toBeGreaterThan(0)
  flush()
}))
```

I'm getting error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`, whcich is related to `expect(component.todos.length).toBeGreaterThan(0)`. Does anybody know why todos isn't updated and code in `getUsers().subscribe` isn't executed?

I tried also `useClass` insead `useValue` with:
`providers: [{ MyServiceService, useClass: MyServiceStubClass }],` and:

```
class MyServiceStubClass {
  getTodos() {
    return of(todosMock)
  }

  getUsers() {
    return of(usersMock)
  }
}
```

...but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the soultion. I had to use:

```
@Injectable()
class MockMyService extends MyService {
  override getUsers() {
    return of(usersMock)
  }

  override getTodos() {
    return of(todosMock)
  }
}
```

and in `TestBed.configureTestingModule`:

```
providers: [{provide: MyService, useClass: MockMyService}],
```

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking you may need to have a `tick` for the `subscribe` to take effect before your `expect`.

Try this:

```
class MyServiceStubClass {
  getTodos() {
    return of(todosMock)
  }

  getUsers() {
    return of(usersMock)
  }
}

providers: [{ MyService, useClass: MyServiceStubClass }],
....

it('should get Users', fakeAsync(() => {
  // first fixture.detectChanges() calls ngOnInit
  fixture.detectChanges();
  // tick should wait for the subscribe to be completed before going to expect
  tick();
  expect(component.users.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
  flush();
}))
```

Comment: I tried with tick() but it doesn't affect. I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Can you do `console.log(usersRes)` inside of the `subscribe` to see what it logs? If it doesn't log, most likely it never makes it there. If it does log, make sure it doesn't log `[]` because that is an array of length zero.

Comment: It doesn't log anything after running the test. After running the app, on the console, I can see an array of 20 items

Comment: Strange, that means it is not making it into the `subscribe` block in the test. I am not sure why, sorry.